# Fullcalendar with node js & mysql

Tags: jquery, mysql, node.js, express, fullcalendar

I want to create a calendar with node js, mysql and express.
Here is my Calendar.js Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        eventSources: [source]
    });
});
```

I have bd mysql "event" table in file bdCalendar.js with data. I don't understand how to transfer data from a table to array source using node js?

bdCalendare.js:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
var bdCalendar = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'admin',
    password: 'admin',
    database: 'event_calendar'
});
bdCalendar.connect((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Connected');
});

bdCalendar.query("SELECT * FROM event", function(err, rows) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        console.log(rows)
    }
 }
});

module.exports = bdCalendar;
```

I will be happy with your help!!!

Comment: what is `[source]` in your code? Is `source` a variable that points to a URL endpoint on your nodeJS server? fullCalendar just uses that to make a HTTP request via ajax to the endpoint (passing in a start and end date that your server should use to filter the list of returned events by) and it expects the response back in the JSON format described in the fullCalendar documentation. Just like any other ajax request, really. Have you created an endpoint in node? If you don't know how, take a nodeJS tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You must have an API endpoint written in node.js, perhaps with Express framework. Fullcalendar is making AJAX requests to that endpoint, you fetch the events and send the list back.